# Bootstrap Scrollspy + pagination - does not work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, scrollspy

I want to add the scrollspy to my pagination but it does not work and I have no idea why!

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".my-pager" data-offset="100">

<div class="container">
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example" class="my-pager">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
      <div id="section1">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>

      <div id="section2">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>

      <div id="section3">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
}

p {
    font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    text-indent: 40px;
}

.pagination {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Check your linkings.

First link jquery to your project before any css, js or bootstrap links.
Then include bootstrap css/js and finally your default files.

Make sure you got the same versions too.

Comment: no. if you remove the fixed positioning, then how can you see what number is highlighted when you scrolling down?